# SVN dump of Apache Lucene’s repository

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I want to take SVN dump of [Apache Lucene’s repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk). How to replicate the above repo to my local machine?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to first create a local repository:

```
$ svnadmin create /path/to/your/repo
```

Once you've created the repository, initialize it for syncing:

```
$ svnsync init /path/to/your/repo /path/to/source/repo
```

Now that you're setup for syncing, sync to the new repository:

```
$ svnsync sync /path/to/source/repo
```

When you don't want to keep the whole repository because you only need a single subdirectory, but you still want the whole history in subversion, you can then create a repository containing only the relevant sections:

```
$ svnadmin dump /path/to/your/repo | svndumpfilter include /path/to/correct/tree \
  > /path/to/filtered/repository/backup
```

We now have a backup that has been filtered to include only the relevant tree.  So, now let's restore that to a new, usable repository:

```
$ svnadmin load --ignore-uuid /path/to/treeonly/repository \
  < /path/to/filtered/repository/backup
```

See the help on [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync), on [repository replication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication), and [repository filtering](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61b/fa09/docs/svn-book-html-chunk/svn.reposadmin.maint.html).

Comment: As apache lucene is not a root folder. svnsync is not able to work. Is there any other way to copy only project dump instead of whole repo dump.

Answer (score 0):

One way to clone an entire Subversion project (with full history) is to use [Git's Subversion bridge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

```
git svn clone http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk lucene
```

By default this will get the entire history of the trunk in Subversion. Be aware that depending on the size, longevity, and complexity of the Subversion repository, this command may take some time to run.

Comment: Git is very good at this. I believe Mercurial also has similar options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the svn command line tool.

```
svn export http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/
```

or

```
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/
```

Use the first if you want a disconnected dump.  Use the second if you want to update and commit.

Comment: I need complete history dump of Repo. So that I can setup local repo with this.